# GridLayout - find child by coordinates x, y

Tags: android, touch, swipe, gesture

I have a very big GridLayout (128x128 cells). I need to detect swipe over every child item. Currently I use OnTouchListener on GridLayout, and this code to detect, over which item user slid.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    int count = glImage.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        CircleImageView ivPart = (CircleImageView) glImage.getChildAt(i);

        if(isPointWithin(x, y, ivPart.getLeft(), ivPart.getRight(), ivPart.getTop(), ivPart.getBottom()))
        {
            // some code
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean isPointWithin(int x, int y, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    return (x <= x2 && x >= x1 && y <= y2 && y >= y1);
}
```

This code works, but is very slow, because every swipe position change causes iterate loop 128^2 times. Is there any better method to get position of child inside GridLayout?

I also tried use onTouchListener for child, but onTouch() was called only on start-item while slide.

Comment: A for loop should NOT be slow by itself, it is slow because you give a new reference to your CircleImageViews at every iteration. Try storing them in an array or List when the Grid is generated. After that i am sure the for iteration would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate in advance all positions of views into array and then use binary search for row (y) and column (x), it will works if child's sizes are immutable.